# Posting a multidimensional associative array with axios will be empty

Tags: vue.js, axios

I tried to post a multidimensional associative array in vue environment but it be empty

```
convertedtext=[[key1:value1,key2:value2],[key1:value1,key2:value2],[key1:value1,key2:value2],[key1:value1,key2:value2]]

const res = await 
        this.$axios.$post("path",convertedtext
        ,{
            headers:{Authorization:`${token}`},
        })
        .then( () => {
        });
```

Looking at the request content in the console is empty

```
[[], [], [], []]
0: []
1: []
2: []
3: []
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two options here:

a) Convert your array to string:

```
convertedtext=JSON.stringify([{key1:value1,key2:value2},{key1:value1,key2:value2},{key1:value1,key2:value2},{key1:value1,key2:value2}])
```

b) use a FormData()

```
   let FormData = new FormData();
   FormData.append('key',value)

    
        this.$axios.$post("path", FormData
        ,{
            headers:{Authorization:`${token}`},
        })
        .then( () => {
        });
```